# Can common libraries appear in two dx projects?

Tags: salesforcedx

In Salesforce DX, I realized one component can only appear at one package at a time. So I am just wondering, can the common libraries like jQuery and Bootstrap appear in multiple dx projects? Or do they need to have separate copies?